# Finding actor/movie rows where actor has multiple distinct roles in the same movie

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select

I got 3 tables, actor (id,name), movie (id,name) and casts(aid,mid,role) (aid is the actor id and mid is the movie id). I was trying to get the output like this:
if an actor had more than 3 distinct roles in the same movie, print all the combinations, like:

```
-1.actor.name, movie.name, role1
-2.actor.name, movie.name, role2
-3.actor.name, movie.name, role3
```

My query is like this:

```
select a.name, m.name, x.role
from actor a,
     movie m,
     (select distinct role
      from casts c
      where c.aid =a.id and c.mid = m.id
      group by c.aid and c.mid
      having count(distinct role) >=3) as x;
```

But I got error message:

> The multi-part identifier "m.id" could not be bound.
>   The multi-part identifier "a.id" could not be bound.

Please point out where my thought went wrong, I want to be able to do this next time. Thanks.

Comment: you should use full table names instead of alias names inside the inner query

Comment: Run a simplified version of sub-query alone, and see if it produces what you expect! The general GROUP BY rule is:
If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your initial query is close, but the problem is that you can only return a single column from a subquery, whereas your `casts` table has a composite key* of two foreign key columns.

Instead, you can do the hard work in a derived table (as you've done in your initial subquery). The benefit of the derived table over the subquery is that you can then join the other tables back to on the two columns to return the friendly column names:

```
select a.name, m.name, c.`role`
from 
(
    select aid, mid
    from casts
    group by aid, mid
    having count(distinct `role`) >= 3
) x
inner join actor a
    on a.id = x.aid
inner join movie m
    on m.id = x.mid
inner join casts c 
    on x.mid = c.mid and x.aid = c.aid;
```

`*` actually, it isn't really a key either, given that the same actor can have multiple roles in the same movie. But we are looking for unique combinations, so its unique after we do the `GROUP BY` on `mid, aid`

[SqlFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8719e/1) - Duplicate Roles are ignored, and the threshold of 3 roles, same movie is observed.

Answer (score 0):

Do a join between the 3 tables, and have a sub-select to verify at least 3 different roles:

```
select a.name, m.name, c.role
from actor a
  join movie m on a.id = m.aid
  join casts c on m.id = c.mid and c.aid = a.id
where a.id in (select aid from casts
               where aid = a.id and mid = m.id
               group by aid, mid
               having count(distinct role) >=3)
```

Comment: we dont have a join on movie and actor

Comment: Can you remove it and see if it works better or not?